# How to share install by Eclipse, or configure two different icons?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse builds java code.  Eclipse EE adds lots of web options.  Eclipse CDT adds C++.

While I can put all of these in a single instance, it complicates things and makes it more confusing for beginners.  I have often told students to just install eclipse/CDT in a different directory, that it will be easier to use on for Java projects, and the other for C++ projects.

However, it's a huge waste of space since most of the code base is the same.  Is there any way to have two or three configurations of Eclipse sharing the same underlying code?

Comment: This is one of the main reasons for Perspectives.

Comment: Perspectives are a mode you get into by clicking. But if you have C++, J2EE and Java all loaded, there are over 20 choices for the kind of file or project to create.    This is not a perspective.